# Manually edit .desktop files added as favorites to Ubuntu dock

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 once again since Ubuntu 17.04 seems out of support.

I wanted to manually edit the entries in my dock, and expected to find a list in `~/.local/share/applications`.

The list does not match my current favorites, meaning that (I assume), it's located somewhere else.

The `/usr/share/applications` directory features a huge list of `.desktop` entries which, again do not match what's in my dock.

I need to edit one of those favorites to add a command-line parameter to the `Exec` entry.

So simply put: **what is the location of `.desktop` files added as favorites to my Ubuntu dock?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
```

You should see the list of `.desktop` files associated to the applications added to the dock in the correct order.

Then look for the `.desktop` file you want to edit in `/usr/share/applications/` or in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 this doesn't work. If I edit file in /usr/share/applications changes work if app is being run via launcher, but it's not working if it's being run from favourites... Specifically adding --ignore-certificate-errors  in google chrome .desktop

Answer (score 3):

Your favourites are just "shortcuts" that point to some *.desktop* files in `/usr/share/applications/` or in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

If you want to add a parameter (or modify in another way) to a *desktop* file, locate the file in the two `applications/` directories:

- if the file is only located in `/usr/share/applications/`, copy it to `~/.local/share/applications/` and edit the copy as you like (you can directly edit without copying, but do prefer to make changes only in your home directory) ;
- if the file is located in `~/.local/share/applications/`, you can edit it directly, but if you want to keep a unchanged version, make a copy in the same directory before editing.

If you edited a copy, you'll need to remove your current favourite and re-add the edited one (since you made a copy, you'll have two *desktop* file in your applications list).